# webhooks: I lose events when I fill in the sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, webhooks

I am using an App script to get data througth webhooks and I have observed that in the local database (webhooks) I have events that I don´t have in my google sheet. I think is because concurrence and maybe I rewrite I cell or something similar.
Anyone could help me?
CODE

```
var SHEET_NAME = "Hoja";
var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

function onOpen() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
// Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
  .addItem('Clear content', 'clearRange')
  .addSeparator()      
  .addToUi();
 }

 function clearRange() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
 sheet.getRange('A2:N').clearContent();//lo hace bien
  }

 function doPost(request){
 console.log(request);
 return handleResponse(request);
  }

 function handleResponse(request) {
 var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
 lock.waitLock(10000);

  try {
  //var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

  var headRow = 1;

  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  var row = []; 
  var postData = JSON.parse(request.postData.getDataAsString());

  for (i in headers){
    row.push(postData[headers[i]]);
   }
   sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);

   return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
   } catch(e){
   return ContentService
   .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
   } finally {
   lock.releaseLock();
   }
    }

 function setup() {
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
 }
```

Comment: Try this: `var postData = JSON.parse(request.postData.contents);`  But in any case take another look at [Request Parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters)  That seems to be the only code that writes to the spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using the special method `getActiveSpreadsheet()` in a WebApp or Apps Script API solution. According to the [Special Methods documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#special_methods) this is not supported.

> **Note**: These methods are only available to bound scripts run from the script editor, menu items, dialogs, sidebars, or triggers. When a bound script is run as a web app or via the Apps Script API, these methods are not available.

I would reccomend to use the `openById()` method that will ensure you are not violating this restriction.

### Reference

[Bound Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound)

Comment: So I have to replace by var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));

Comment: No, the id should be the Sheet ID. You can retrieve it on its URL: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/**this-is-the-id-string**/edit#gid=0`

Comment: When I use this var doc= SpreadsheetApp.openById, I don´t have events in google sheet. If I use the old one, I have events but I lose some of them...

Comment: Sheets events are available only from the script editor not when the script runs as a WebApp. Refer to this documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#special_methods

Comment: Sorry Alessandro but I didn´t undertand your response. I tried to change getactivespreadsheet() by openbyID as you suggested. When I use the first one, I have data in my google sheet but sometimes I lose information. When I use openbyId() i don´t have any data.

Comment: What do you mean by `I don't have any data`? Is not opening the same file? How are you retrieving the Spreadsheet ID?